# Python Iterate through dictionary to normalize json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

From an API Call, I return a dictionary that looks like:

```
{'detectedLanguage': {'language': 'en', 'score': 1.0},'translations': [{'text': 'ハローワールド。これは楽しいです', 'to': 'ja'}, {'text': '世界您好。这很有趣', 'to': 'zh-Hans'}, {'text': '전 세계 여러분 안녕하세요. 이것은 재미', 'to': 'ko'}]}
```

I know I can loop like:

```
for i in response[0]['translations']:
    print(i)
```

Which returns these three dictionaries:

```
{'text': 'ハローワールド。これは楽しいです', 'to': 'ja'}
{'text': '世界您好。这很有趣', 'to': 'zh-Hans'}
{'text': '전 세계 여러분 안녕하세요. 이것은 재미', 'to': 'ko'}
```

However, I'm not sure how to get them into the dataframe. Is there a solution using json.normalize?

The length of the list of dictionaries will vary, but what I'd like to do is iterate through the 'translations' key to create a dataframe that looks like:

```
Language     Text
ja           'ハローワールド。これは楽しいです'
zh-Hans      '世界您好。这很有趣'
ko           '전 세계 여러분 안녕하세요. 이것은 재미'
```

Language = 'to' and Text = 'text'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(response["translations"])[["to", "text"]].rename(columns={"to": "Language", "text": "Text"})

  Language                    Text
0       ja        ハローワールド。これは楽しいです
1  zh-Hans               世界您好。这很有趣
2       ko  전 세계 여러분 안녕하세요. 이것은 재미
```